# 'Unknown props' error when using react-tab-panel

Tags: reactjs

I'm receiving an error when trying to implement the [react-tab-panel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tab-panel) in my application. I've followed the installation instructions to no avail.

[image: Error in console]

This is the code which is producing the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import TabPanel from 'react-tab-panel'

const tabStyle = (props) => {
  const baseStyle = {
    padding: 10
  }

  return Object.assign(
    baseStyle,
    props.active?
      { color: 'red' }:
      { background: 'gray' }
  )
}

const ExperimentDetail = ({ tabStyle }) => (
  <div className="experiment-detail">
    <TabPanel
      tabAlign="center"
      tabStyle={tabStyle}
    >
      <div tabTitle="first tab"> first </div>
      <div tabTitle="second tab"> second </div>
      <div tabTitle="third tab"> third </div>
    </TabPanel>
  </div>
);

export default ExperimentDetail;
```

The output is showing up as so, which is close to correct but with slight errors.

[image: Current output]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you are using `active` props in `TabStyle`, but you are not passing in from `ExperimentDetail` component. One more thing you need to change, you need to use `TabStyle` name instead of `tabStyle`, because each `react` component must start with a uppercase.
And the **main point** is `TabStyle` is a `react` component, it will not return an object, it will return a html part so you can't use it with styling.

Use it in this way:

If you want to make a generic function that will `return` the style object, then write it in this way, create a separate file `abc.js`, put that `function` in that file, like this:

```
export function tabStyle(active){
  const baseStyle = {
    padding: 10
  }

  return Object.assign(
    baseStyle,
    props.active?
      { color: 'red' }:
      { background: 'gray' }
  )
}
```

`Import` this `function` in your component:

```
import {tabStyle} from './abc /*path to this file*/';
```

Then use it in this way:

```
const ExperimentDetail = () => (
  <div className="experiment-detail">
    <TabPanel
      tabAlign="center"
      tabStyle={tabStyle(true)}
    >
      <div tabTitle="first tab"> first </div>
      <div tabTitle="second tab"> second </div>
      <div tabTitle="third tab"> third </div>
    </TabPanel>
  </div>
);

export default ExperimentDetail;
```

Check the working `jsfiddle` example: https://jsfiddle.net/ghoLrkjj/